# assigning value to the byte

Tags: java, byte, wrapper

what is the difference between this two

```
Byte i1=new Byte(1);//complier error
byte b=1;//ok
```

my question is about assigning the value 1 to byte where 1 is int literal.
but when passing 1 to the Byte class constructor it gives error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The value 1 is a literal of type integer. So you have the following situations:

- Assigning the literal directly to a variable of type `byte` will cause an implicit conversion since it is obvious that the programmer wants a byte and not an int.
- The `Byte` ctor takes a `byte` value, the compiler complains since it can't do an implicit conversion for method or ctor arguments.

Answer (score 3):

`Byte` is an object. `byte` is a primitive. Amongst other things, this means that a `Byte` reference can hold `null`.

Answer (score 3):

`Byte i1` is an Object, while `byte b` is a primitive type. new `Byte(int)` is not a valid constructor for Byte object. see [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html)

Answer (score 0):

Byte and byte are two different keywords, if I'm not mistaken.

Or is Java not case sensitive?

Answer (score 0):

Byte i1=new Byte(1);//complier error

error is because Byte constructor accepts only `byte` or `String` object as value

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#Byte(byte)

Answer (score 0):

A compile-time error will occur because you are passing an integer to the constructor of the Wrapper class Byte, the compiler will not do the implicit casting here.

The method invocation conversions specifically do not include the implicit narrowing of integer constants which is part of assignment conversion.

Answer (score 0):

"Byte" is a Class, "byte" is one of the default data type.
The similar example is "Integer" and "int".

Back to the question, the compile is coming from Byte accept "byte" or "String" as the parameter.
So, please try to modify the code to

```
Byte i1=new Byte((byte)1);
```

or

```
Byte i1=new Byte("1");
```